# Ambari fails restarting : The package hive-metastore is not supported by this version of the stack-select tool

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I build a hadoop cluster with Ambari 2.7.3.0. Ambari notifies we need to restart some components, but I get the following error message when I restart them.

I guess there are some version issues as the message mentions.

> Fail: The package hive-metastore is not supported by this version of the stack-select tool.

Is it due to the limited connection to the internet? Because of security issues, we use a local repository.

Unfortunately, I'm very new to Ambari and hadoop, so I cannot find any clue in this message.

```
2019-03-14 13:20:46,629 - Reporting component version failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 363, in execute
    self.save_component_version_to_structured_out(self.command_name)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 223, in save_component_version_to_structured_out
    stack_select_package_name = stack_select.get_package_name()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/functions/stack_select.py", line 109, in get_package_name
    package = get_packages(PACKAGE_SCOPE_STACK_SELECT, service_name, component_name)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/functions/stack_select.py", line 234, in get_packages
    raise Fail("The package {0} is not supported by this version of the stack-select tool.".format(package))
Fail: The package hive-metastore is not supported by this version of the stack-select tool.
2019-03-14 13:20:46,676 - Reporting component version failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 363, in execute
    self.save_component_version_to_structured_out(self.command_name)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 223, in save_component_version_to_structured_out
    stack_select_package_name = stack_select.get_package_name()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/functions/stack_select.py", line 109, in get_package_name
    package = get_packages(PACKAGE_SCOPE_STACK_SELECT, service_name, component_name)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/functions/stack_select.py", line 234, in get_packages
    raise Fail("The package {0} is not supported by this version of the stack-select tool.".format(package))
Fail: The package hive-metastore is not supported by this version of the stack-select tool.
```